# mysql error message: #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: laravel, mariadb, mariadb-10.6

Recently I installed this 2 years old laravel template with php 7.4.
Template was working smoothly before, but now getting this error.

When import the database on phpmyadmin:

mysql error message:

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`idif6594_test`.`#sql-alter-cd0b6-1b44b2`, CONSTRAINT
> `content_details_language_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`language_id`)
> REFERENCES `languages` (`id`))

SQL query:

---- Constraints for dumped tables
---- Constraints for table `content_details`

```
ALTER TABLE `content_details`  
  ADD CONSTRAINT `content_details_content_id_foreign` 
      FOREIGN KEY (`content_id`) REFERENCES `contents` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `content_details_language_id_foreign` 
      FOREIGN KEY (`language_id`) REFERENCES `languages` (`id`);
```

And when I tried to login to the dashboard, laravel give this error:

ErrorException

> Trying to get property 'success' of non-object
>
> Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError
> vendor/jlang/jsonstringfy/src/Services/RequestResolve.php:32

======

phpmyadmin

Server version: 10.6.16-MariaDB-cll-lve - MariaDB Server

Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 8.1.27

PHP extension: mysqli, curl, mbstring

PHP version: 8.1.27

Comment: Without seeing the actual SQL which generated this error we cannot provide a fix.  But your error is a common one; did you try searching for it on this site?  It usually happens because you are adding or updating a record in a child table using a foreign key value which has no equivalent primary key in the parent table.

Comment: Your stack is running on PHP 8.1.27, which introduces breaking changes from PHP 7.4. Ensure that all your dependencies are compatible with PHP 8.1.